# returning a value after for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, I have been trying for the past few hours to get an result out of a function after performing some for loops :

```
Cluster.prototype.initiate_api_data_fetching = function(username) {
var self = this,
    object = [];

return self.initiate_available_market_search(username, function(data_object){
    var json_obj = JSON.parse(data_object);
    for(var obj_key in json_obj) {
        for (var i = json_obj[obj_key].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            self.initiate_market_items_data_fetching(username, json_obj[obj_key][i].site, function(data_obj){
                var json_object = JSON.parse(data_obj);
                for(var data_key in json_object) {
                    for (var j = json_object[data_key].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        object.push(json_object[data_key][j]);
                        /*log(object);*/
                    };
                };
                log(object);
            });
        };
    };
});
};
```

Making abstraction of all the variables and other things that make no sense to you readers, I would just like to know how can I return the `object` array with the data that I\m pushing in it. Everything is fine if I\m logging where the `/*log(object);*/` is, but if I want to see what the object contains at the end of the function, I get an empty array.

Comment: Oh man. 4 nested `for` loops? Are you sure?

Comment: The first time you call `Cluster.initiate_api_data_fetching`, you do realize you're not actually performing any loops, right?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik ~ What other option do I have ? I need to first loop through an array with 3 indexes ( it can be any number of indexes ), then depending on what I get from there I loop through three other arrays I get from another request and I need to save every value ( in my case it will be objects ) in a separate array

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem ~ What do you mean by that ?

Comment: Just had a closer look, and boy: FFS: a closure on a prototype method: any instance will share the same closure members: 4 instances will share 1 value for `username` - Is that really what you want? I mean: 1st instance calls `Cluster.prototype.initiate_api_data_fetching('userA')`, the prototype anon function returns the actual method which then has access to `'userA'`, which (since that's what closures do) cannot be undone all too easily, _but_ you have an argument in the return function with the same name, so why use the closure in the first place? this is _VERY_ error-prone code, sorry

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ~ what do you suggest then ?

Comment: @Roland: phew, erm... don't know where to start with that. It's just code that is going to break, IMO: the anon function you've assigned to the prototype returns a new function object, so why assign it the prototype? That defeats the purpose, sort of, unless it's invoked immediately, in which case the value of `username` would have a comparable status as a protected property in traditional OO languages, unfortunately, the first argument of the return function has the same name, so which variable is the interpreter to choose? the argument, of course. The closure var goes out of scope

Comment: So why bother with code that is harder to maintain and therefore more likely to break? the `object` array isn't that expensive of a variable to create when the method is called, and, in your case, that would be the only benifit as far as I can work out

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ~ Oh ... so regarding the assigning the proto, this is just one method out of many other methods that need the `this` pointer. So if you think that I only have one function and I shouldn't prototype for just one function, then you should know that I would not do it for just one function (:

Comment: @Roland: a book? ;-P No, seriously, at this point I couldn't seriously suggest anything even half decent, because I haven't even seen the constructor, I just know that you have an object with 2 methods. But my first step would be either use a closure, or a prototype, not combine them at a prototype level

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ~ Regarding the other parts, the `username` variable needs to be the same as it will be the same values for both passed along the whole method

Comment: @Roland: No, I'm all for prototypes when it comes to shared methods, but the prototype has a method, that, when it's first called _returns a new function_, which will -in all likelyhood- override the instance's method. So effectively, your prototype method acts as a function factory. Iterate over an instance and check if `hasOwnProperty('initiate_api_data_fetching ');`, after it has been called. it'll be true (would be false if it used the prototypemethod), so each instance has its own little function _AND_ the prototype has one, so that's one more compared to assigning the method @constructor

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ~ I have enough books (: Yeah, I only needed a solution, because I actually haven't refined the code, it's just in development for now so there is a lot of work to do ... and I know that what I provided it's not enough for making the right assumption (:

Comment: @Roland: then rename the first argument of the return function, if I were to pass `bar` to the anon function, `username === 'bar'`, but if I then call the method again and pass `foo` as first argument --> `username === 'foo'` or better still, don't make it an argument at all, if it'll always be the same, don't provide the opportunity to change its value

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ~ OK, so I should have a separate argument and not the same. I shall follow that advice (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add a callback to your main function and call it when done..

```
Cluster.prototype.initiate_api_data_fetching = function (username, callback) {
    var self = this,
        object = [];

    return self.initiate_available_market_search(username, function (data_object) {
        var json_obj = JSON.parse(data_object)
            , counter = 0;

        function done() {
            counter -= 1;
            if (counter === 0) {
                callback(object);
            }
        }

        for (var obj_key in json_obj) {
            if (!json_obj.hasOwnProperty(obj_key)) { continue; }

            for (var i = json_obj[obj_key].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                counter += 1;
                self.initiate_market_items_data_fetching(username, json_obj[obj_key][i].site, function (data_obj) {
                    var json_object = JSON.parse(data_obj);
                    for (var data_key in json_object) {
                        if (!json_object.hasOwnProperty(data_key)) { continue; }

                        for (var j = json_object[data_key].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                            object.push(json_object[data_key][j]);
                            /*log(object);*/
                        }
                    }
                    done();
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

**PS. 1** assumption is that initiate_api_data_fetching is async.
**PS. 2** Follow the advice from the commenters above to improve your code. I answered your immediate question by showing you how to synchronise async calls, but don't stop there.

Comment: It is async ( the data fetching from the API if that\s what you mean ) (:

Comment: In that case you definitely need to pass in a callback function! :-)

Comment: If I place the callback where you have it it's going to execute as many times as I', looping, and I only want the final result. If I am placing the callback outside the loops it will be empty, so what can I do in this situation ?

Comment: You will need to synchronise. I updated my code example using a counter.